# Knockout Mapping data bind not working

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using the latest KO Mapping Plugin. The idea is the Details section should be populated with JSON data retrieved from Ajax Call.

```
var supervisorVM = {
        supervisor: ko.observable()
    };

-----------code to call custom data service which returns JSON---
     if (supervisorDetails) {
        $('#Detail').show();
        supervisorVM.supervisor = ko.mapping.fromJS(supervisorDetails);
        ko.applyBindings(supervisorVM, document.getElementById("Detail"));
    }



<div id="Detail" class="side-widget" style="display:none">
    <h2>Details</h2>
    <strong>
        Supervisor<br>
        <span data-bind="text: supervisor.FullName"></span><br/>
    </strong>
    <span data-bind="text: supervisor.PhoneNumber"></span><br/>
    <a data-bind="text: supervisor.Email, attr: { href : 'mailto:'+supervisor.Email() }"></a>
</div>
```

Everytime I run the Detail section doesn't get populated with supervisor details i.e. Fullname and Phone Number.

I debugged and confirmed that supervisorVM.supervisor is populated but data bind doesn't work.

Also tried below no luck:

> supervisorVM.supervisor(ko.mapping.fromJS(supervisorDetails));

I spent more than 2 hours already, can someone please help what have I done wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: well its working fine for me check here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/74dh736s/16/ . if you can reproduce the issue in fiddle its easy to sort it out.

Comment: The fact that you're making a query call to show the Detail div rather than using a boolean observable along with applying the binding so specifically to the DOM element makes me think you aren't using knockout appropriately and is probably the reason behind most of your struggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bindings such as `supervisor.Fullname` are defined incorrectly - you are looking for a property 'Fullname' on the *observable function*. It should be `supervisor().Fullname`.

Try wrapping the fields in a `with: supervisor` binding. This has the nice side effect that the fields aren't rendered, as long as your AJAX call hasn't returned and added content to `supervisor`:

```
<div id="Detail" class="side-widget" style="display:none" data-bind="with: supervisor">
    <h2>Details</h2>
    <strong>
        Supervisor<br>
        <span data-bind="text: FullName"></span><br/>
    </strong>
    <span data-bind="text: PhoneNumber"></span><br/>
    <a data-bind="text: Email, attr: { href : 'mailto:' + Email() }"></a>
</div>
```

Also, do not replace observables, as you do here:

```
supervisorVM.supervisor = ko.mapping.fromJS(supervisorDetails);
```

Instead, replace their *contents*:

```
supervisorVM.supervisor( ko.mapping.fromJS(supervisorDetails) );
```

Your markup is already bound against the old observable you assigned with `supervisor: ko.observable()`. You can replace that observable with a new one, but your markup remains bound to the old one — it will never update again.

Comment: `defined incorrectly` Actually it is correct way(based on his code) to do because he is not `pushing` data to observable he is assigning `=` . well if he needs to do your way(preferable way) using `()` he have to implement like this : http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/74dh736s/17/

Comment: When you replace an observable that is bound somewhere with a new observable, that binding will not update anymore. Thanks for the heads up — I will include that part in the answer.

Comment: actually his code works fine you can check my comment with fiddle attached there .

Comment: I checked your fiddle, and you are assigning data, not replacing the observable? `supervisorVM.supervisor(data);`. Anyway, that doesn't really matter — replacing observables is a very bad practice that leads to bugs that are quite hard to track down, so I strongly suggest never to do that in the first place.

Comment: correct ! we should avoid doing that in 1st place . `supervisorVM.supervisor(data);` this is way to replace isin't it ?. Well in the fiddle in my comment to question very top (not the comment with fiddle to you answer) i tried `=` my bad just to play around and test why really its not working but it seems to work . cheers

Comment: Yes, because you assign it before you bind. That's not what would happen when the data is changed _after_ binding: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/janfoeh/74dh736s/19/).